# Question regarding de-referencing structure pointers

Tags: c, pointers, structure, dereference

I am compiling this piece of code and I get compilation errors saying " dereferencing pointer to incomplete type" . 
I get the errors for the last print statement and before that where I try to point (*temp). num to the address of b

```
void main()
{

    struct {
        int xx;
        char *y;
        int * num;
        struct x *next;
    }x;

    struct x* temp;
    int b = 10;

    temp = ((struct x *)malloc(sizeof(x)));

    (*temp).num = &b;

    x.next = temp ;

    printf(" %d\n",temp->num, x.next->num);

}
```

Comment: `main()` returns an int. To make your program more portable use `int main(void) { /* ... */ }`. And you don't need to cast the return value of `malloc()`, it is much better to `#include <stdlib.h>`. And `(*temp).num` can be written `temp->num`.

Comment: Oh ... and your `printf` expects 1 argument besides the format string and you pass it 2.

Comment: You should not cast the return value of malloc(), in C.

Comment: @pmg and @unwind see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688034/doubt-regarding-de-referencing-structure-pointers-please-explain/1688154#1688154

Comment: Thanks for the answers and comments. 

Just to be absolutely clear, I understand that I have not assigned a "tag" or "type" to the structure, but just declared a "variable" or "instance" called x. 

So whenever later, I juse struct x, it is confusing because there is no "type/tag" called x. Its like doing int * when "int" itself is not defined. Is my thinking correct? 

So the way I look at it, what I have done is just get a variable of special type called "x" through which I can access an int, a char *, an int * and an unknown pointer. Is this correct too?  

Thnx for your patience

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the statement:

```
struct {
   ...
} x;
```

defines an unnamed instance 'x' - not a named type 'x'.

So when you refer to 'struct x' from within there all the compiler knows is that you want some pointer of type 'x' - which you'll define later (and you never do).

To define a named type 'x' you need:

```
struct x {
   ...
};
```

Comment: That does not define a named type 'x' - it's just a struct tag. To define a named type you would need a typedef.

Comment: @Draemon - Partially true - it defines a struct named 'x'...  In straight C you can't use 'x' without the 'struct' part but it's still named as opposed to OP when it was unnamed.

Comment: @Aaron: It defines a struct named "struct x", not a type that is a struct that is named "x". Structs tags and type names are distinct namespaces, in C.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant:

```
struct x {
  int xx;
  char *y;
  int * num;
  struct x *next;
}x;
```

You reference a "struct tag" that you haven't defined wherever you use `struct x`. You have no way to refer to the type of variable `x`. Since you want to refer to it with `struct x` you must define the struct tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the fact that your struct refers to itself before it's completely defined.

In particular, your struct has no name; "x" is the name of a variable having such a structure, but there is no type name.

Just declare "`struct x { ... } x`" and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Besides what Draemon write about `struct x {...} x`, I took the liberty of correcting the various other small problems like the `printf()`:

```
void main()
{
  struct x {
    int xx;
    char *y;
    int *num;
    struct x *next;
   } x;
   struct x* temp;
   int b = 10;
   temp = ((struct x *)malloc(sizeof(struct x)));
   (*temp).num = &b;
   x.next = temp ;
   printf("%d %d\n",*temp->num, *x.next->num);
}
```

Just out of curiosity: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `void main()` has never been a valid prototype for `main` in C or C++.

If you want to pointer to the `struct` you are declaring within the `struct`, you need to tag the `struct`. The  `typedef` is sometimes useful, but not necessary.

Please study the differences between your code and the following and understand why the differences are there. That will help you learn. So will reading the [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/) (e.g. see [Structures, Unions, and Enumerations](http://c-faq.com/struct/index.html).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int b = 10;

    typedef struct x_struct {
        int xx;
        char *y;
        int *num;
        struct x_struct *next;
    } x;

    x *temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp));
    if ( !temp ) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    temp->num = &b;
    temp->next = temp;

    printf("%d %d\n", *(temp->num), *(temp->next->num));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, 
In your code, did you want to say  
x_struct * temp = malloc ..

instead of 
x *temp = malloc... 

Please clarify. Also if you can look at the comment I have added at the top (for the question) summarizing my understanding. If you can have a quick look, will be great 

Thanks.

Comment: I did mean `x *temp = malloc(...)`. `struct x *temp` would have been fine as well. However, why not use the `typedef` now that we have typedef'ed it?